# Assert 2-d list in python

Tags: python, assert

In python, I am trying to check if a given list is a 2-d list.  I am supposed to use an assert statement but I don't know how to create one.

So far I have

```
assert type(x) == list
```

I know that this is incorrect and checks for a 1-d list.  How do I fix this?

Comment: `assert isinstance(x, list) and all(isinstance(y, list) for y in x)`?

Comment: What do you call a 2D list? a list of lists? Do the inner lists have to be the same length?

Comment: For our class, a 2D list is [][]

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko that assumes an empty list is a valid 2-D list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe good point.

Comment: To reject empty lists, we can append `and x` as in `assert isinstance(x, list) and all(isinstance(y, list) for y in x) and x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this...

`l=[[]]
assert type(l) == list and type(l[0]) == list`

but I get an indexError for the one dimensional case so I used this instead...

```
l=[]
try:
    assert type(l) == list and type(l[0]) == list
except IndexError:
        assert False

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
AssertionError
```

Maybe there is a better way but it's not obvious to me.

A better (but long winded) way might be...

```
 assert type(l) == list and len({ type(el) for el in l }) == 1 and { type(el) for el in l }.pop() == list
```

Comment: Ah no, this is incomplete as it only tests element 0. Never mind!

Comment: This will fail for `[["dog"], "cat"]`.

Comment: I had another try!

Comment: @Yakym Pirozhenko  has the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

to check if x is a list you already did

`assert type(x) == list`

to check if x is a list and elements of x are a list -

```
assert type(x)==list
assert reduce(lambda a,b : type (b) == list and a, x, True)
```

to check if x is a list and elements of x are a list and each element is the same length -

```
assert type(x)==list
assert reduce(lambda a, b: type (b) == list and a, x, True)
l = len(x[0])
assert reduce(lambda a, b: len(b) == l and a, x, True)
```

Instead of `reduce` you could use `all` which makes it more readable.

to check if x is a list and elements of x are a list and each element is the same length -

```
assert type(x)==list
assert all([type(i) == list for i in x])
l = len(x[0])
assert all([len(i) == l for i in x])
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, I have been debating this while writing actual code too. Is using `reduce, map, filter` hated by python people?

Comment: imo `reduce` has it's place, but here `all` is simpler. You get away with one fewer function call and the `all` gives a good visual hint that the return type is `bool`.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Thanks. I didn't discover `all` before today.